# Exclude column/list of columns while loading into dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a weird question or issue which I am facing, my parquet file is having around 1200 columns out of which few are corrupt columns for some reason. I can't edit the files for some reason so I want to exclude those columns from being introduced to a data frame I want to create. I don't seem to find any such feature which would help me to do so.
The idea of creating a data frame first and then dropping the columns do crossed my mind but that can't be done because getting the issue of

```
   Failed to merge incompatible data types string and bigint
```

So any way we can exclude the columns before hand even before loading in called is welcomed. Declaring a schema is going to be tedious job which I want to avoid at any cost because I want to keep the process as dynamic as possible.
Any leads or ideas are more than welcome.

Thanks
Ashit

Answer (score 1):

can you provide some more information?
do all files have the same schema? except for some "corrupted" columns - which seems that they have a different type?

if this is the case - I would recommend not avoiding providing a schema. you can do something like this (this is the scala version) :

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("path to on file that has a good schema")
      val allColumns = df.columns.toSet //get all columns
      val goodColumns = allColumns - "badColumn"
      val allData = spark.read.parquet("path to all data").select(goodColumns: _*) //syntax for exploding the set and providing the strings
```

spark should project only the needed columns and skip the corrupted once
you can also do the same with getting the schemaType from one file drop the not needed columns and provide this schema